# How to set two interceptors in axios

Tags: javascript, api, post, axios

I have two functions that using axios post information to different APIs I created with node and express. Both of them have an interceptor as I get a response from by backend with messages, errors, and other information. Yet when I post the to the second url ("/users/login") the first interceptor still fires off (in the addUser instead of the findUser function) even though it is not in the same function. How do I fix this?

```
async function addUser(user) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    try {
      const interceptorResponse = axios.interceptors.response.use(
        (response) => {
          if (typeof response.data === "object") {
            let success = response.data.registerSuccess;
            let errors = response.data.errors;
            let data = response.data.data;
            let message = response.data.message;
            setData(() => {
              return { ...data, errors, registerSuccess: success, message };
            });
          }
          return response;
        }
      );
      await axios.post("/users/register", user, config);
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(interceptorResponse);
    } catch (err) {}
  }
  async function findUser(user) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    try {
      axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (typeof response.data === "object") {
          let loginSuccess = response.data.data.loginSuccess;
          let message = response.data.message;
          console.log(response.data);
          setData(() => {
            return { ...data, loginSuccess, message };
          });
        }
        return response;
      });
      await axios.post("/users/login", user, config);
    } catch (error) {}
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you're adding the interceptors globally to axios. Use axios.create() to make an axios instance, than add the interceptor to just that instance - any requests made through that instance will use that interceptor, all others will not. (Refer to the documentation for more details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I still didn't 100% understand. Can you write in pseudo code, using comments, or my code so that I can understand it better? Is it exactly the same except you add axios.create()at the beginning? Do I put my post request somewhere else?

Comment: `function addUser() { const axios = axios.create(); axios.interceptors.response.use(...); await axios.post(...) }`

Comment: Though, you mentioned that you're already doing `axios.create()` at the beginning of the file? If this is so, then perhaps you want to make an axios-creator function that you use within each function, instead of having a single axios instance for the entire module. e.g. `const createAxiosInstance = ({ ...someConfigIncludingSomeDefaultOptions }) => axios.create({ ...someConfigIncludingSomeDefaultOptions }); function addUser() { const axios = createAxiosInstance(); axios.interceptors.response.use(...); await axios.post(...) }`